# Instance of custom object being replaced when another is created java

Tags: java

I have code like,

```
public class ComplexSO {
    public static double real;
    public static double imaginary;

    public ComplexSO(double cReal, double cImaginary) {
        real = cReal;
        imaginary = cImaginary;
    }

    public static ComplexSO selfSquare() {
        return new ComplexSO(Math.pow(real, 2) - Math.pow(imaginary, 2), 
            2 * real * imaginary);
    }

    public static ComplexSO add(Complex other) {
        return new ComplexSO(real + other.real, imaginary + other.imaginary);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComplexSO c = new ComplexSO(1, 2);
        System.out.println("c.real = " + c.real + ", c.imaginary = " + c.imaginary);
        ComplexSO d = new ComplexSO(2, 3);
        System.out.println("c.real = " + c.real + ", c.imaginary = " + c.imaginary);
    }
}
```

and when I run this I get the output:

`c.real = 1.0, c.imaginary = 2.0`

`c.real = 2.0, c.imaginary = 3.0`

I am not new to object oriented languages (C++ and python), but I am new to java, and this simply makes no sense to me. Please halp.

Comment: get rid of static declarations on real/imaginary members. and read this - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-static-members-of-a-Java-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, static properties of a class are *global*. There is only one value per class definition. Similarly, static methods operate globally and not on class instances. Simply remove static from `real`, `imaginary`, `selfSquare`, and `add` and you should see the correct behavior. Your `main` method will need to remain static.

Answer (score 1):

Because each instance of a class references the same copy of a static variable

So the line `ComplexSO d = new ComplexSO(2, 3);` references to the static variables double and imaginary and therefore overwrites the previous values 1 and 2